# Error running .exe compiled with i586-mingw32msvc-g++ and SFML on linux

Tags: c++, makefile, sfml, mingw32, wine

EDIT: Thanks random downvoter!

EDIT 2: Thanks @πάνταῥεῖ for explaining what was wrong with the question. When running a debugger I get

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0046f4c6 in ?? ()
```

EDIT 3: This only happens if I run the cross compiled program. If I compile the program in Windows and run it with WINE, nothing wrong happens.

So well, I'm fighting with WINE and MinGW32 right now. 
So I have a file, `sortem.cpp` which is compiled with a Makefile and linked and all from that Makefile.

sortem.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main ()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(720,480),"Sort 'em!");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                window.clear();
                switch (event.type)
                {
                    case sf::Event::Closed:
                        window.close();
                }
                window.display();
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
LD = ../bin
LIBS= $(LD)/sfml-window-2.dll $(LD)/sfml-system-2.dll $(LD)/sfml-graphics-2.dll $(LD)/sfml-network-2.dll $(LD)/sfml-audio-2.dll
OBJECTS= sortem.o
CXX= i586-mingw32msvc-g++
all: sortem.exe

sortem.exe: $(OBJECTS)
     $(CXX) -o ../bin/sortem.exe $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $<

clean:
     rm *.o
```

So the program compiles perfectly, but when running `sortem.exe` with WINE, it says the program must exit. I click "Show details" and this pops up. `Unhandled exception: page fault on write access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x0046f4c6).`and a lot of hexdumps. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, maybe the SFML libraries aren't up to date? But that'd give me a compile error, not a runtime error... Thanks a lot for the help, guys.

Comment: It wasn't a _random downvote_! Your question is lacking a lot of information necessary to solve your problem. 1st: What did you notice, when running your program in the debugger? 2nd: What are the stack traces actually telling you? etc.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then a comment, like yours, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's generally expected on SO you do all of the mentioned efforts beforehand asking. So it's not necessary to leave comments on bad questions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Excuse my error then. I'm adding an edit right now to address your 1st demand.

Comment: If you type `bt` or `where` into gdb, it will show you where you came from before the crash. This is most of the time a good place to start typing `up` to see what your code was actually doing. Something is obviously NULL that isn't expected to be NULL.

Comment: @MatsPetersson 0x0046f4c6 in ?? () doesn't look good at all. I expected a function name. Does this have something to do with the fact that wine is running the program?

Comment: @ChemiCalChems Step upwards the stack, to see where you came from.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ keep getting (ADDRESS) in () ??. No function names are ever shown. But wait a second... If there are entries for 0 to 10... Does that mean the error is ocurring at line 11? That could be something. Seems to lead to window.display();

Comment: May want to actually generate debug symbols using the `-g` option in your compile. (e.g. `$(CXX) -g -c $<`)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thanks, but its working now with another toolchain.

Comment: I saw that, but you will need to learn to debug at some point - unless getting that bit of program to work was your last ever project...

Comment: @MatsPetersson In fact, it's failing again. I think it's WINE's fault. You are right. I should do that, and learn how to debug a program. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: So, add -g to your compile and link command, and you SHOULD get a better backtrace. I doubt that you are exposing bugs in Wine with a simple program - more likely you are hitting some undefined behaviour due to something you do in your code... ;)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Actually, the program works perfectly on Windows. I'm installing a Virtual Machine for that right now, and I'll test. If it works on the VM and not on Ubuntu, it's WINE's fault. Otherwise, I'll debug.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, if I compile my program with g++ 4.8.2 and the dlls are compiled with g++ 4.8.1 they wont work will they? Thats what may be happenning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libraries were compiled with MinGW GCC 4.7.1 and I was trying to compile my program with MinGW GCC 4.8.1, downgraded thanks to a friend and back online it is. Thanks you guys all for having shown me how to debug. 
Peace